# Cmake find_package does not detect path in windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, ceres-solver

I am trying to build the ceres sovler using Cmake_gui and Visual Studio

I have ceres-solver cloned to **E:\Code\libs\ceres-solver**
and the required library Eigen3 cloned to **E:\Code\libs\eigen-3.3.9**

When I run cmake-gui on ceres-solver, I get the following error:

```
-- Detected available Ceres threading models: [CXX_THREADS, OPENMP, NO_THREADS]
-- Building with C++14
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:242 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I modified ceres CMakeLists.txt line 241
from:

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
```

to

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED PATH "E:/Code/libs/eigen-3.3.9")
```

But I still get this error above

I also tried

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "E:/Code/libs/eigen-3.3.9")

set(Eigen3_DIR "E:/Code/libs/eigen-3.3.9")
```

My questions are:

1. What is the correct way to specify the path for find_package? Do I need to use path environment variable within windows or modify CMakeLists.txt?
2. Am I specifying this path correctly in Windows? Do I need to link to some internal directory of Eigen3? Like `E:\Code\libs\eigen-3.3.9\cmake`, use forward slashes instead of back slashes, or use quotation marks for the path? I tried all of these things without success.
3. Does find_package recursively search for the package within the directories specified? Or do I need to point to the exact directory?

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure, but the directory specified contains the built libraries, and not just the cloned source of `Eigen3`

Comment: just the source code, I though CMake would build everything into 1 project

Comment: `find_package` searches for built cmake packages and not for the sources. I think there is a way to build it together with the main project, but I'm not sure how exactly to configure that.

Comment: You need to use CMake to generate a project and build Eigen3 separately for you. You can also use vcpkg to help do this for you: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

Answer (score 1):

According to comments:

I must run Cmake-Gui on Eigen3 first, to generate a Build directory. However, it does **not** necessarily need to be built in VS afterwards,

Then setting on line 240 in CMakeLists.txt for ceres-solver

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "E:/Code/libs/eigen-3.3.9/build")
```

Was sufficient for Cmake-Gui to find the Eigen3Config.cmake file

Notes:

1. Eigen3 does not have any required dependencies it seems, but it does throw a lot of warnings when generating with Cmake-Gui, I ignored these
2. glog library or any other libraries are not required, but I did have to check "Enable mini-glog" option and re-run config for ceres-solver.